# Regexp for parsing words from sentence

Tags: php, regex, string

I need a regular expression to parse words from a sentence or a paragraph. Some separaters that should be used are: spaces, and dots. So in:

```
My name is Bob.I'm 104 yrs old.
```

`Bob` and `I'm` are seperated even though there isn't any space between them, but a dot.

Any other regular seperaters of words should also be included.

Comment: What have you done? I would check RegExpLib.com, but we are not here to do the work for you :), though would be glad to help

Comment: I don't know regexps hence i'm posting here. I was going to do `$words = explode(' ', $text)` but i need other seperaters in addition to spaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$words = preg_split('#[\\s.]#', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The `\\s` will match all white space characters (such as space, tab, new line, etc).  The `.` will match, well a `.`...  If you wanted to add more characters, just add them after the `.` (with the exceptions that a `[`, a `]` and a `#` must be escaped with `\\`, and a `-` must be the last character in the list)...

It will return for your above sentence:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "My"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "name"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "is"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "Bob"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "I'm"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "104"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "yrs"
  [7]=>
  string(3) "old"
}
```

Comment: Heh, good to know about the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY - avoids needing the `+` I used in my answer.

Comment: Need some help. Can you tell me how to add comma (`,`), `<word>` and `</word>` to the list of characters that would seperate words? so: `<word>company,firm,business</word>` would be seperated into 5 elements, and `<word>` and `</word>` would be included in them

Comment: Adding a comma is easy: `'#[\\s.,]#'`...  As for `<word>` and `</word>`, http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html  (In other words, NEVER parse XML/HTML with a regex)...

Answer (score 9):

What about [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)?:

> For the purpose of this function, 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string containing alphabetic characters, which also may contain, but not start with "'" and "-" characters.

Example:

```
$str = "My name is Bob.I'm 104 yrs old."; 
print_r(str_word_count($str, 1, '0123456789'));
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => My
    [1] => name
    [2] => is
    [3] => Bob
    [4] => I'm
    [5] => 104
    [6] => yrs
    [7] => old
)
```

The third parameter takes a string which defines which additional characters should be considered as "word characters".

Comment: Yep, using built-in functions is always the preferred option, because they're much more likely to cater for potential edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to do this, either inclusive or exclusive, by splitting on either of the following:

Use "word characters", plus common "connectors" (apostrophe,hyphen,etc), and negate the whole group:

```
[^\w'-]+
```

Or specify what you consider non-word characters (spaces, dots, colons, parens, etc):

```
[\s.;:()]+
```

(In both cases, the `+` avoids empty groups being created.)

Certain characters need to be escaped in character classes - for details see http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (\b or \w) to isolate individual words from whitespace and punctuation.

Comment: This will fail on words such as `I'm`, which was explicitly stated as a requirement in the question.

Answer (score -1):

have a look at [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split)

```
$words = preg_split('/\W+/', $sentence); // split on non-word-characters
```

this will obviously split »I'm« into ›I‹ and ›m‹

Comment: As you noted, this will fail on words such as `I'm`, which was explicitly stated as a requirement in the question.